# Anonymous array workaround/alernative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an 'anonymous array' but it seems there is no such thing, is there some technique that would allow me to omit the array_of_objects: property from the G: object but keep everything else the same?

[image: screen clip of editor and app debug UI]

Comment: don't post pictures of code; there's not a single array in your picture, there are some object literals though

Comment: FWIW, `array_of_objects` is actually an object, not an array.

Comment: Change `var array_of_objects = {};` to `var cells = [];` and `return {cells: {array_of_objects}};` to `return {cells};` or even `return cells;` ?

Comment: If I do that, I get:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: The error means that you are trying to render each or one of the objects you create (`{id: x}`) as react component. You should not do that and change how you render these values. Since you are not showing how you are rendering the values, there is not much more we can say. The error is already pretty self-explanatory. In a nutshell: if I have `var value = {id: 0};` I cannot do `<span>{value}</span>`. If I want to render the value of the property `id`, I'd have to access that property: `<span>{value.id}</span>`.

Comment: Lots of other questions for that error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Objects+are+not+valid+as+a+React+child

Answer (score 1):

Since [ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), this:

```
{ array_of_objects }
```

is considered the same as

```
{ "array_of_objects": array_of_objects }
```

It's creating a property with that name. If you don't want this property, all you need to do is remove the curly braces:

```
return { cells: array_of_objects };
```

Comment: this is exactly what I tried hours ago but got the following error:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I thought I just made an obvious mistake, is there another way to remove the property with the same name?

Comment: You should also follow @Felix's advice to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution (if I understood your question correct)

```
setup: function() {
  var cells = {}; // Better to use [], but nm
  for(var x = 0; x< 121; x++) {
    cells[x] = {id:x}
  }
  return { cells: cells }
}
```

Comment: Same with the other answers, I get the error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.